# Is UPDATE / DELETE atomic per row or as a whole?

Tags: sql

When I have an UPDATE- or DELETE-statement: is it atomic per row or as whole?

So does it virtually locks or deletes all the rows it is affecting at a single point in time?

Comment: The answer may depend on which DBMS you're using

Comment: Could you please add the relevant tags to your question, eg [tag:sql-server], [tag:mysql], [tag:oracle]

Comment: I think that's such a basic issue that there should be a determination in the standard.

Comment: Not all DBMS's are ACID compliant. Here's some good reading on the subject ~ http://www.methodsandtools.com/archive/archive.php?id=83

Comment: Both options here are ACID in a different flavor. One per statement, one per row. So what's the standard-way?

Comment: each locking level is managed by the db engine so  ..  so this depend of the db brand/version you are really using ..there  is not a standard ..if you tell us the db you areally using someone can give more detailed  explanation

Comment: So does the standard give the freedom to implement that in both flavours?

Comment: No, the standard defines that this happens in an atomic way, but not all DBMS products adhere to that standard. See [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=ee6d6c8a1a326d5cb11064e671b10b39) vs [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ee6d6c8a1a326d5cb11064e671b10b39)

Comment: Interesting issue. But I told something different: If I have an UPDATE-transaction on a table that affects multiple rows, are this rows virtually locked (UPDATE) at an atomic point in time so that _another transaction_ can't see an incremental locking as the first transaction proceeds?

Comment: You also asked about DELETE, not only UPDATE. But regarding the UPDATE: that again depends on the DBMS. Postgres and Oracle do behave that way (locking all rows "at once").